# High Charts Live Data multiple series from php files

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest, highcharts

Im fairly new to js and php , I am trying to load a live chart with mutliple series of btc price from exchanges from php files. Ive tried and failed, i can only get 1 of the data series to load , they all work individually but getting all of them to load as seperate points on the chart at the same time eludes me.

BITSTAMP.PHP -- results:  [1519417809000,9932.83]

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
function bitstampbtcusdgetprice($url)

{   $decode = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($decode, true); }

$x = time() * 1000;
$y = 
$btcusdgetprice('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btcusd');
$btcusdtickerprice = round(($y["last"]), 2);
$ret = array($x, $btcusdtickerprice);
echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

CHART.JS

```
var chart; 

function requestDatabitstamp() {

$.ajax({

    url: 'php/bitstamp.php',
    success: function(point) {

        var series = chart.series[0],
            shift = series.data.length > 100; 

        chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);      

        setTimeout(requestDatabitstamp, 30000);

    },

    cache: false
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {

chart = new 

    Highcharts.Chart({

    colorAxis:{     gridlineColor: '#4c4c4c'},
    marker:{        animation: '10000'},

                    chart:{ renderTo: 'container',
                            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                            backgroundColor: '#141414',
                            borderColor: '#00A578',
                            plotbackgroundColor: '#161616',
                            parallelAxes: {linecolor: '#4c4c4c'},
                            events: { load: requestDatabitstamp}},

    tooltip:{       style: {color: '#FFFFFF',
                    fontSize: '10px'},
                    backgroundColor: '#141414',
                    borderRadius: '12'},

    title:{         text: '<font style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:verdana;">Exchange Comparison</font>'},

    plotOptions:{   series: {
                    color: '#00A578'}},

    xAxis:{         type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 50 * 1000},

    yAxis:{         minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,

    title:{         text: '<font style="color:#00A578;font-family:verdana;">USD</font>',
                    margin: 30}},

    series: [{      color: '#00A578',
                    name: '<font align="center" style="color:#00A578;font-family:verdana;">Bitstamp</font>',
                    data: []

    }]});});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the data properly loaded, but you cannot display it using highcharts? Or is there already a problem while loading the data in PHP?

Comment: the problem is i want multiple points on the graph , but i dont know how to implement it, the code works , but when i try to get another data series on the graph from another exchange , i fail

for example , i would like to load okex.php , binance.php alongside bistamp.php on the graph , individually they all work , but i want to combine them , not sure what i need todo

Comment: Then let me ask you again: is the data properly printed to your markup such that your problem is the configuration of highcharts?

Comment: yes , the data is fine , getting it to load up in highcharts combined is my prob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert with Highcharts but what I see is that you are filling only chart.series[0] with points so only one series is printed. You have to have series for each exchange.

Update:

Try creating an array filled with the data for each exchange in the PHP file and receiving it through AJAX, then create points for chart.series[1] and chart.series[2].

Comment: understood , ive tried many ways of implementing the code to load up on another series, im sure its a minor issue im overlooking , just need to be steered in the right direction.

Comment: can you provide an example ? i tried , but not getting the desired result

Answer (score -1):

got it , heres the updated code. i had the other series i tried importing in the wrong places.

```
function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/binance.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[0],
            shift0 = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is 
                                             // longer than 20

        // add the point
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift0);

        // call it again after one second   
    },
    cache: false
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/bitstamp.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[1],
            shift1 = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is 
                                             // longer than 20

        // add the point
        chart.series[1].addPoint(point, true, shift1);

        // call it again after one second  
    },
    cache: false
});
    $.ajax({
    url: 'php/bittrex.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[2],
            shift2 = series.data.length > 50; // shift if the series is 
                                             // longer than 20

        // add the point
        chart.series[2].addPoint(point, true, shift2);

        // call it again after one second
        setTimeout(requestData, 10000);    
    },
    cache: false
});
}
```

Comment: What happens when you add third series and a third function called by events?

Comment: it didnt work , i actually just figured it out and got it working now :)

Comment: You just did what I told you to do :))

Comment: yes , you didnt explain entirely , but its all good , im the type to keep trying , you did lead me in the right direction though , it took me a couple hours to figure out exactly how to organize the code , raspect fam!